# SonarQube Analysis failing to recognize new component

Tags: sonarqube, salesforce, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Hi We are using sonarqube in our project and we have a very particular requirement where we need to do analysis only on new code.

So Suppose my master branch is having 5(A,B,C,D,E) components. I am running my first analysis on master branch to baseline all existing issues.

Using the same project key, I am running the second analysis on my branch from master or release specific branch (This is being done to highlight issues on new code only). At this point of time my release branch only contains 2(A1,B1) components where A1 = A + modification. "This works perfectly fine and highlight only new issues introduced".

Problem occurs on my 3rd analysis if a new component says C1 (C + modification) has been added to the branch. At this time SonarQube is treating C1 as completely new component and reporting all issues as new although they were existing in master branch (On C component).

TimeMachine feature shows since Baseline (version name of first analysis) but always marking issues from last analysis.

We Are using SonarQube 5.6 community version

Comment: You might want to take a look at the guide on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because currently your situation is not clear. You say you "add 1 more class" and then complain that the whole class is treated as new. Well... it should be. You just added it.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam : Edited my question. In case there are still clarifications required do let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I correctly understand your situation, I think you will benefit greatly from upgrading to at least the current LTS: 6.7.1, if not to the current version: 7.0. Since 5.6, we've done some significant work on issue backdating. Assuming your analysis has access to SCM blame info, issues raised outside the relevant time period won't be shown as "new".

That said, I think you're going about it wrong. IMO all your analyses should include all your files, and by correctly setting the leak period (and benefiting from issue backdating) you'll be able to segregate truly new issues from old ones.

Comment: Leak period is working fine !
The only problem occurs as per the below scenario.
Suppose my first analysis runs on components ( A, B, C,D and E) with version 1. now during my second analysis only components (A,B) were present with version 2 .
Now during my 3rd analysis if I add component C along with A,B then although the leakperiod is configured to check against version 1 , sonarqube treats component C as new component as it was not available in last analysis (version 2) . Hope this clears my situation and question